# How do I increase a value by a number (cps) every second on single view?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been looking at previous questions, however, they seem to be outdated or do not work for my case. In my application I want to increase a variable (money) every second by another variable (cps). When I try doing forever loops or using timers, I either get errors or nothing occurs.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var money = 0
    var cost = 20
    var clicks = 1
    var cost2 = 50
    var CPS: Int = 0
    var truth = true

    @IBOutlet weak var costOutlet2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cpsButtonOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var clicksButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var clicksOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cpsOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreOutlet2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var costOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cpsBtnOutlet: UIButton!

    override func prepare(for backsegue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let controller = backsegue.destination as! ViewController
        controller.money = Int(scoreOutlet2.text!)!
        controller.clicks = Int(clicksOutlet.text!)!
        controller.CPS = Int(cpsOutlet.text!)!
        controller.cost = Int(cost)
        controller.cost2 = Int(cost2)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        costOutlet2.isHidden = true
        costOutlet.isHidden = true
        costOutlet.text = "\(cost)"
        scoreOutlet2.text = "\(money)"
        clicksOutlet.text = "\(clicks)"
        cpsOutlet.text = "\(CPS)"
        errorLabel.isHidden = true
        clicksButtonOutlet.setTitle("$\(cost): +1 Clicks", for: .normal)
        cpsBtnOutlet.setTitle("$\(cost2): +1 CPS", for: . normal)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        scoreOutlet2.text = "\(money)"
        clicksOutlet.text = "\(clicks)"
    }

    @IBAction func addClicks(_ sender: Any) {
        if (money >= cost) {
            money = money - cost
            scoreOutlet2.text = "\(money)"
            cost = cost * 3
            clicks = clicks + 1
            clicksOutlet.text = "\(clicks)"
            (sender as AnyObject).setTitle("$\(cost): +1 Clicks", for:[])
            print(cost)
        } else {
            insufficent()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addCps(_ sender: Any) {
        if (money >= cost2) {
            money = money - cost2
            scoreOutlet2.text = "\(money)"
            cost2 = cost2 * 3
            CPS = CPS + 1
            cpsOutlet.text = "\(CPS)"
            (sender as AnyObject).setTitle("$\(cost2): +1 CPS", for:[])
        } else {
            insufficent()
        }
    }

    func insufficent() {
        errorLabel.isHidden = false
        errorLabel.text = "Insufficent Funds"
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.5) {
            self.errorLabel.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently trying to make a clicker game on Swift 4 Xcode 10, I am able to make the CPS increase when it is purchased, however, when it is bought the value of money does not go up every second. How can I make the variable "money" increase by whatever the value of "CPS" is.

Comment: The code you posted makes no attempt to update anything every second. Please show what you tried and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the code in your viewController

```
/...
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    increaseMoneyEverySecond()
}

private func increaseMoneyEverySecond() {
    money = money + CPS
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) { [weak self] in
        if let strongSelf = self {
            strongSelf.increaseMoneyEverySecond()
        }
    }
}
/...
```